# How do I instantiate an attribute that is declared as a bean in the spring config?

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, instantiation

I have a pretty simple solution I'm trying to solve:

I have my DAO object:

```
package com.me.dao;
@Service
public class JavaNeo4jConnection implements Neo4jConnection {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private DriverManagerDataSource dataSource;

    public void setDataSource(DriverManagerDataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);
    }

}
```

And I have declared the dataSource in my springConfig.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.me.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.me.servlets" />

<!-- Servlet --> 
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<!-- dataSource bean-->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${neo4j.dburl}" />
    <property name="username" value="${neo4j.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${neo4j.password}" />
</bean>

<!-- Config properties file-->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The dao object is being instantiated using Autowiring from my servlet controller:

```
package com.me.servlets;

@Controller
public class JsonServer {
    @Autowired
    Neo4jConnection neoConn;

    @RequestMapping("/servejson")
    @ResponseBody
    public void serveJson(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response
    ) throws IOException {

        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();       

        String json =  neoConn.getInfo(request.getParameter("query"));

        os.write(json.getBytes());
        os.close();
        os.flush();

    }

}
```

But the dataSource is never instantiated, running my code will produce a `NullPointerException`.

What am I missing here? I'm fairly sure I'm misusing `@Autowired`.

Comment: Where are you getting a `NullPointerException`? Where and how do you use the `JavaNeo4jConnection` bean?

Comment: Do you component scan the package containing the `JavaNeo4jConnection` class?  `JavaNeo4jConnection` must be a bean in order to have its fields autowired.  Post the entire config file.

Comment: You might getting npe on jdbcTemplate, if so try to put the autowire annotation on the setter

Comment: Need to see how you use the `JavaNeo4jConnection` class.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Adding the @Autowired annotation to the method fixed it. Can you post that as an answer and explain how `@Autowired` works with respect to applying to to methods and attributes?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've added some details, hopefully that's useful.

Comment: @dwjohnston You should take a look at `@RequestParam`.  You really don't need to pass the request and response to that controller handler method.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
@Service
public class JavaNeo4jConnection implements Neo4jConnection {
```

and

```
<context:component-scan ... />
// or <context:annotation-config /> which is redundant if you have the 'component-scan'
```

Spring will instantiate your `JavaNeo4jConnection` bean. During that process, it will scan the members of the class for `@Autowired` (among other things). If it finds a field annotated with it, it will try to resolve a bean and inject it. If it finds a method annotated with it, it will look at the parameters and try to resolve appropriate beans and use them as arguments when invoking the method.

Since you only have a field annotated

```
@Autowired
Neo4jConnection neoConn;
```

Spring will use field injection directly. It will assign the bean it finds to the field. It won't invoke your setter method and therefore won't initialize the `JdbcTemplate` field.

One solution is to move the annotation to the setter method (method injection).

Another solution, with field injection, is to replace your setter method with a `@PostConstruct` annotated method

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // dataSource has been injected
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);
}
```

Or use constructor injection

```
@Autowired
public JavaNeo4jConnection(DriverManagerDataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);
}
```